# UK Skilled Worker Visa application - Is my job on the shortage occupation list?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa

I'm looking to submit my skilled worker visa application. My job title is Teacher of Spanish, French and English. The shortage occupation list for education states that teachers of foreign languages are on the shortage occupation list, but teacher of English is not. In my case where I teach both non-shortage and shortage subjects, should my job be considered shortage occupation? On my CoS it states no, and I believe this is a mistake? If yes, can it be fixed by adding a sponsor note?